# "The page isn’t redirecting properly" error in codeigniter

Tags: php, controller, codeigniter-3

i tried to check if user has session in login page, if he has session and role id this controller will redirect to certain controller. but it gave me error `"The page isn’t redirecting properly"` instead.
here's my code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('username') == null) {
            if ($this->session->userdata('role_id') == 1) {
                redirect(base_url('back/admin'));
            } else {
                redirect(base_url('back/user'));
            }
        } else {
            redirect(base_url('back/auth'));
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data = ['title' => 'Log-in page'];

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('un', 'Username', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pw', 'Password', 'required|trim');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('back/login', $data);
        } else { }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('username');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('role_id');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">you\'re session has been deleted</div>');

        redirect(base_url('back/auth'));
    }

    public function errorp()
    {
        // $this->load->view('back/error');
        echo 'not authorized';
    }
}
```

i tried many things to solve this redirect error, but still can't find way how to fix this or the way i'm redirect was wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

certainly, there is an error in logout function.

Try fixing it:

(before)

```
'<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">you're session has been deleted</div>'
```

(after)

```
'<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">you\'re session has been deleted</div>'
```

Comment: thanks,i updated the code ady, but still not fixing my problem lol

Comment: Mh ... Try to delete all base_url functions. You can use redirecti function without specifying base_url ... the redirect function should automatically add the base URL.

Comment: i fixed the prob. by myself, i need to check the session inside my index, no need to check inside __construct, it keep redirecting to the same controller that's why i got that error.

Comment: and also if i didnt put base_url() inside my redirect function, it give me result index.php/myblablablacontroller in address bar. i even modified .htaccess tho but still give me the same result

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for this error

i need to check the session inside my index, no need to check inside __construct, it keep redirecting to the same controller that's why i got that error.